# Do i have to write in shader language to create a FX file?

Tags: c++, directx

Is there a program out there, that would create a FX file instead of having to code it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to create shaders without coding at all, I don't know of any such software.

But, [FX Composer](http://developer.nvidia.com/fx-composer) and [RenderMonkey](http://developer.amd.com/archive/gpu/rendermonkey/pages/default.aspx) are good programs to create shaders in!